# How do I force jsonStringify to output an array without quotes?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, geojson

I am using a Google Apps script to format data from a Google spreadsheet into geoJSON by calling [jsonStringify](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#jsonStringify%28Object%29). My code is modified from [this original example](https://raw.github.com/mapbox/geo-googledocs/master/MapBox.js). Each row in the spreadsheet represents a country, with a single cell containing the relevant geoJSON polygon data:

```
[[[74.92,37.24],[74.57,37.03],...[73.31,37.46],[74.92,37.24]]]
```

But since that cell doesn't contain a number, jsonStringify is parsing it as a string, returning this:

```
"coordinates":["[[[74.92,37.24],[74.57,37.03],...[73.31,37.46],[74.92,37.24]]]"]
```

...which I can't use, since the quotes make it non-valid geoJSON. When I enter a single number, jsonStringify returns it without the quotes, I assume because it recognizes that it's a number. Is there some way I can force it to interpret the polygon data as a number or otherwise escape the quotes? Here is the relevant section of my code:

```
function getObjects(data, keys) {
  var objects = [];
  var headers = getHeaders(sheet, activeRange, 1);

  var zip = function(keys, data) {
    var obj = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        obj[keys[i]] = data[i];
    }
    return obj;
  };

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var obj = zip(headers, data[i]);

//this is the polygon data
    var poly = obj[settings.poly];

    var coordinates = [poly];

    // If we have an id and polygon data
    if (obj[settings.id] && poly) {
      // Define a new GeoJSON feature object
      var feature = {
        type: 'Feature',
        // Get ID from UI
        id: obj[settings.id],
        geometry: {
          type: 'MultiPolygon',
          // Get coordinates from UIr
          coordinates: coordinates
        },
        // Place holder for properties object
        properties: obj
      };
      objects.push(feature);
    }
  }
  return objects;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of passing a *string* to `jsonStringify` as the "coordinates", pass an *actual array*. That is, use [`jsonParse`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#jsonParse%28String%29) first on the original text (as required) to obtain the relevant object.

An example conversion (with guard that may or may not be appropriate) might look like:

```
function restoreCoordinatesFromText(source) {
    var geo = Utilities.jsonParse(source);
    return (geo && (geo instanceof Array)
            ? geo                 // looks like we got our [array of stuff]
            : theSourceData);     // dunno, let's act like we never saw it
}
```

Then later on the *actual coordinate array* can be encoded correctly in JSON while the string exhibits the initial undesired behavior.

```
var coords = "[1,2,3,4]"; /* just a string */

var json = Utilities.jsonStringify({
                     /* array, good! */
    goodCoordinates: restoreCoordinatesFromText(coords),
                     /* string, bad! */
    badCoordinates:  coords
});
```

Here is the [corresponding fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VtDZa/1/) (it utilizes ES5 JSON support).

Comment: Thanks so much! I was able to get it working with your answer.